# Range-Time Radar Data Processing

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, radar

I am learning to how it is working this data processing. But I am little bit a confused. There are different ways to obtain this range-time table.
As you can see the picture, obtaining the range-fft data directly settled to the range bin table. I want to ask. Shouldn't there be just as many boxes as the more adc sampled from each chirp signal, instead of the big red block on the range pod side? For example, our adc sample is 1024, can we say that the size of this matrix from top to bottom is 1024?

[image]

In this picture like as I said, Here, if we want to sample the adc data as much as the chirp signal, we do it. Then we take the fft of this adc data as the number of adc samplings and we get the value of the if signal. Using this frequency value, we can calculate the distance data and write these values in the boxes.

I want to be sure about this how it is working this  process.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the big red box on the range pod side?

Comment: range-bin slow time axis graph in which the values obtained after the fft process in the first photo are written